# Datatable does not export second row in footer

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have this datatable issue where I am not able to export second row of footer in excel. below is the snippet. when I export footer 1 is there in the sheet but footer 2 is not.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'excelHtml5', footer: true },
        ]
        
    });
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Footer 1</th>
            <th>Footer 1</th>
            <th>Footer 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Footer 2</th>
            <th>Footer 2</th>
            <th>Footer 2</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you check my answer below? If it didn't work for you, please let me know so I can review it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately `DataTables` does not support multi-row table footer, but there is a customize function which allows to customize the XLSX file:

> `customize`
>
> Since: 1.2.0
>
> This method can be used to modify the XLSX file that is created by
>   Buttons. The first parameter that is passed in is an object that
>   contains the XML files and the object structure matches the file
>   system paths for those files in an XLSX file. Customisation of the
>   XLSX file is a complex topic - please refer to the *Customisation*
>   section in the [`excelHtml5 button`](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) documentation for full
>   details.
>
> As of Buttons 1.5.2 this function is passed three parameters:
>
> 1. An object that contains the XML files in the ZIP file structure used by Excel
> 2. The button configuration object
> 3. A DataTables API instance for the table the button belongs to.

We can utilize the `customize` callback and combine it with reading the table footer and then adding the extra footer rows to the XML XLS using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#table').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        footer: true,
        customize: (xlsx, config, dataTable) => {
          let sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
          let footerIndex = $('sheetData row', sheet).length;
          let $footerRows = $('tr', dataTable.footer());

          // If there are more than one footer rows
          if ($footerRows.length > 1) {
            // First header row is already present, so we start from the second row (i = 1)
            for (let i = 1; i < $footerRows.length; i++) {
              // Get the current footer row
              let $footerRow = $footerRows[i];

              // Get footer row columns
              let $footerRowCols = $('th', $footerRow);

              // Increment the last row index
              footerIndex++;

              // Create the new header row XML using footerIndex and append it at sheetData
              $('sheetData', sheet).append(`
                <row r="${footerIndex}">
                  ${$footerRowCols.map((index, el) => `
                    <c t="inlineStr" r="${String.fromCharCode(65 + index)}${footerIndex}" s="2">
                      <is>
                        <t xml:space="preserve">${$(el).text()}</t>
                      </is>
                    </c>
                  `).get().join('')}
                </row>
              `);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
            <td>body</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Footer 1</th>
            <th>Footer 1</th>
            <th>Footer 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Footer 2</th>
            <th>Footer 2</th>
            <th>Footer 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Footer 3</th>
            <th>Footer 3</th>
            <th>Footer 3</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Just copy/paste and it works... Didn't expect that, thanks a lot.